# How to Extract Part of a String using Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have been trying to extract part of string in bash. I'm using it on Windows 10. Basically I want to remove "artifacts/" *sfscripts_artifact*_  and ".zip"

Original String

```
artifacts/online-order-api_sfscripts_artifact_1.5.6-6.zip
```

I've tried

```
input="artifacts/online-order-api_sfscripts_artifact_1.5.6-6.zip"
echo "${input//[^0-9.-]/}"
```

Output

```
--1.5.6-6.
```

Expected Output

```
online-order-api 1.5.6-6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
s='artifacts/online-order-api_sfscripts_artifact_1.5.6-6.zip'
awk -F_ '{gsub(/^[^\/]*\/|\.[^.]*$/, ""); print $1, $NF}' <<< "$s"

online-order-api 1.5.6-6
```

Or else this `sed` solution:

```bash
sed -E 's~^[^/]*/|\.[^.]+$~~g; s~(_[^_]+){2}_~ ~;' <<< "$s"

online-order-api 1.5.6-6
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution using only variable expansion, consider:

```
input='artifacts/online-order-api_sfscripts_artifact_1.5.6-6.zip'

part0=${input%%_*}
part0=${part0##*/}
part1=${input##*_}
part1=${part1%.*}

echo "${part0} ${part1}"
```

Output:

```
online-order-api 1.5.6-6
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357633/8344060) of adebayo10k, but in the order indicated by the user:

```
# Remove .zip from the end
tmp0="${input%.zip}"
# Remove path
tmp1="${tmp0##*/}"
# Extract version (remove everything before last underscore)
version="${tmp1##*_}"
# Extract name (remove everything after first underscore)
name="${tmp1%%_*}"
# print stuff
echo "${name}" "${version}"
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in pure `bash` using the `=~` operator.

```
[[ $input =~ .*/([^_]*).*_(.*)\.[^.]*$ ]] &&
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

prints out

```
online-order-api 1.5.6-6
```

with the given input.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input,

```
echo ${input#artifacts/}
```

seems to me the simplest approach. This uses your assumption that you know already that the preceding path name is *artifacts* and leaves `input` unchagned if it has a different structure. If you want to remove **any** starting directory name, you can do a

```
echo ${input#*/}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mawk 'sub("_.+_"," ",$!(NF=NF))' OFS= FS='^.+/|[.][^.]+$'
```

```
online-order-api 1.5.6-6
```